# How to provide password when use pfx file in c# on mono?

Tags: .net, ssl, f#, mono

I want my program support tls,this code can run on windows:

```
let store = new X509Store(StoreName.Root)
store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadWrite)
let certs = store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindBySubjectName,"TestServer", false)
let x509 = certs.[0]
```

I want to use tls on linux with mono too,but linux may not have location like `StoreName.Root` to save certificate

I find this way:I can use pfx certificate file directly:
`let x509=new X509Certificate2(path,password)`

so on linux,I can use openssl to generate pfx file,then I can use tls

but there is a problem:how to provide password?

if I let user write password in config file like this:

pfxpassword=111111

it's terrible,so is there any way let me provide password?

or is there other way let me can use tls on linux with mono?